# Is 250mb/month enough bandwidth to support the internet needs of 4 mining rigs?

Tags: mining-pools, network, stratum, bandwidth

So this question was posed in 2011; I figure by now there may be slightly different factors at work, but mainly I ask if i can use a prepaid hotspot plan for 250mb to connect 4 sp20 mining rigs each clocking ~1.5 Terrhashes/sec.. I can get a higher bandwidth plan, but it's significantly more expensive and so I seek the input of you fine folk :)

Comment: Are you mining with a pool, solo, via p2p-pool?

Comment: stratum pool, I probably should have mentioned hehe-slush's to be exact